# cant install vue-property-decorator

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I was trying to install vue and typescript on class style by  vue-property-decorator  but i don't know why i get this type of script after creating the project

i was expecting this type of script :

```
<script lang="ts">
import {Component, Vue} from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({
  components: {},
})
export default class App extends Vue {


}
</script>
```

buuutt
i am just getting this type instead :

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
export default Vue.extend({
  
})
</script>
```

Comment: It's specific to the way you init the project, not Vue itself. This means that the choice of vue-property-decorator doesn't affect the generated code

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `vue-class-component` first, as it's a required peer dependency (i.e. is not provided by `vue-property-decorator`)

See https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator :

> This library fully depends on `vue-class-component`, so please read its README before using this library.

`vue-class-component` docs: https://class-component.vuejs.org/

---

If you are getting this after project initialization, that means either that the initializer is incorrect (e.g. `quasar` incorrectly initializes `script setup/ts` as `script options/js`), or you didn't choose ClassComponent when CLI was asking for if you gonna use it